# Sort UL by price with vanilla JavaScript with IE11 support

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-5

Very simplicity I'm trying to sort an unordered list by the price only using vanilla JS and it needs to have IE 11 support. 
 I'm getting a error of`document.querySelector(...).innerHTML` and also not sure if `Array.prototype.slice` is supported in IE11 despite checking https://caniuse.com/

 Heres what I've done:

```js
function sort(){
  var productsContainer = document.querySelector('.products-grid');
  var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.products-grid > .product'));
  console.log("els" + els)
   els.sort(function(a, b) {
    na = parseInt(a.querySelector('.price-item--regular > span').innerHTML);
    nb = parseInt(b.querySelector('.price-item--regular > span').innerHTML);
    document.querySelector(".products-grid").innerHTML((nb - na));
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sort()"> sort</button>
<ul class="products-grid">
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" style="visibility: visible;">£2.96</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" data-product-id="" style="visibility: visible;">£5.71</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
    <span class="money pre-money" data-product-id="" style="visibility: visible;">£5.71</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet takes each item and snips of the currency symbol with "substring(1)" then pushes each item to an array. It then sorts the array and replaces each innerHTML attribute. Hope this helps!

```js
function sort() {
  var productsContainer = document.querySelector('.products-grid');
  var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.products-grid > .product'));
  var unsorted = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    unsorted.push(els[i].querySelector('.price-item--regular > span').innerHTML.substring(1));
  }
  var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].querySelector('.price-item--regular > span').innerHTML = "£" + sorted[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sort()"> sort</button>
<ul class="products-grid">
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" style="visibility: visible;">£111.96</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" data-product-id="" style="visibility: visible;">£10.10</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" data-product-id="" style="visibility: visible;">£5.71</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" style="visibility: visible;">£8.31</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using JQuery this is a much cleaner method:

```js
function sort() {
  var productsContainer = document.querySelector('.products-grid');
  var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.products-grid > .product'));
  els.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.querySelector('.price-item--regular > span').innerHTML.substring(1) - b.querySelector('.price-item--regular > span').innerHTML.substring(1);
  });
  $(productsContainer).append(els).html(); // THIS IS JQUERY
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sort()"> sort</button>
<ul class="products-grid">
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="a">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" style="visibility: visible;">£111.96</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="b">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" data-product-id="" style="visibility: visible;">£10.10</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="c">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" data-product-id="" style="visibility: visible;">£5.71</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <img src="" alt="d">
    <div class="price-item--regular">
      <span class="money pre-money" style="visibility: visible;">£8.31</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Oops I don't know why this took me so long to realise and maybe it was my fault for not being more specific but I need the LI to be sorted as well. Right now only the spans are being sorted by price. I've created as JSfiddle if your not sure what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/sn4qLa12/

Comment: Hi so I have worked out a much easier way of sorting the products while maintaining each of their own product containers but I am having trouble finding a way of reinserting the sorted array into your html without jquery

Comment: Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jacob_roling/9wrd8t6c/